# Problems after upgrading to php 5.5

Tags: php, upgrade, ioncube, directadmin

We just recently upgraded our server to php 5.5 now our wefact stopped working and it gives us this error code:

Site error:

```
the file /home/supreme/domains/wefact.supremehosting.nl/public_html/bestellen/application    /wefact_functions.php requires the ionCube PHP Loader  ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the ionCube Loader Wizard to assist with installation.
```

So as far as im knowing what this error means, we need to upgrade our ioncube, but we have no clue how.

if we use the php -v command on the server we get this:

```
[root@s01 ~]# php -v

Failed loading /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: undefined symbol: execute

Failed loading /usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Nov 18 2015 11:02:07)

Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

[root@s01 ~]#
```

And before i forget to tell you guys, we are using direct admin, and some guys told us there are custom ion builds for direct admin.

Comment: You are trying to load ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so which is for PHP 5.3 .
If you are unable to configure your ioncube correctly contact your support

Answer (score 0):

Please install latest ioncube for php 5.5.

Check here: http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-admin/howto-installing-ioncube#installing_ioncube_php_extension